# How to convert the special characters to normal values using java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, utf-8

I'm accepting different language values by converting the value to htmlEscape.

Example a Greek value `Όνομα , name = Όνομα; htmlEscape(name);` its output is `&#x38c;&#x3bd;&#x3bf;&#x3bc;&#x3b1;` saving value.

Now I want this value to be converted back in Java, I used `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml("&#x38c;&#x3bd;&#x3bf;&#x3bc;&#x3b1;");` it's showing me question mark like this: `????`.

Same thing I tried in Java application, it worked fine, but when comes to web app it's not working. I'm using Eclipse IDE.

Comment: That looks like a problem happening when the output is *displayed* rather than when it is processed. How are you displaying the resulting string, and are you sure that whatever you're using for that purpose is Unicode-enabled?

Comment: Please show more code.

Comment: I enabled unicode now.Printed those values in console, works fine.Actually i have to display those values in excel sheet.Their its showing question marks ????.